# How to create circular Container in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

How can I create a circular container items to create the effect of circular movement like a carrusell in codenameone?

When the last element showed in the screen arrise the visibility, then the first item it show from bottom and if I touch this container to UP, then the first item it showed from below of the container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in a layout since components map to specific locations. However, List supports this functionality using:

```
list.setFixedSelection(List.FIXED_NONE_CYCLIC);
```

Comment: but you recomend that not use list.How can I create this effect?

Comment: Sure but it isn't deprecated. List isn't ideal but that's one of the few effects that's exclusive to list

Comment: I suggest you implemented in the Container because I think that you will deprecate list.

Comment: Currently list isn't deprecated and we have no plans to do so. This specific feature is one of the reasons why list can't be deprecated

Comment: could you provide an example to create a Custom Container the permitt circular components?

Comment: I don't like to use list because is very difficult to update its style individually

Comment: There's no support for that in Container. I'm not sure I would know how to add support for that to Container.